# In Bash, how do you find and crop a string around a wildcard pattern

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, unix, pattern-matching

I want to crop a string around a wildcard (or a pattern using a wildcard) in Bash, preferably using parameter expressions or grep, anything but sed if it's possible. And then get that wildcard in a variable.

Example of string:

```
DESERT=pie-cake_berry_cream-sirup
```

And I have a pattern with a wildcard:

> _*_

The pattern will match with "_berry_" on my string. I want to run a bash command over my string, and return "berry" if I use this particular pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `BASH_REMATCH` to access the captured group:

```
if [[ $DESERT =~ _(.*)_ ]]; then
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

This says: hey, take the variable `$DESERT` and capture whatever is placed in between `_` and `_`. If there is such match, the result is captured in the special variable `$BASH_REMATCH`.

So in your example:

```
$ DESERT=pie-cake_berry_cream-sirup
$ if [[ $DESERT =~ _(.*)_ ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
```

Returns

```
berry
```

From [`man bash` - Bash variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables):

> **BASH_REMATCH**
>
> An array variable whose members are assigned by the ‘=~’ binary
>   operator to the [[ conditional command (see Conditional Constructs).
>   The element with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the
>   entire regular expression. The element with index n is the portion of
>   the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression. This variable
>   is read-only.

Comment: Fantastic. Kudos for fast answer.